# Linux copy parameters to other program

Tags: linux, script, shell-script

I have made a script
 `ocrun param1 param2`
  that calls another program like
`oprun param1` ..

i would like somehow param3 and all following (parami) to be copied to oprun.. ex:

```
 `ocrun param1 param2 param3 param4   

`oprun param1` param3 param4
```

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slice the argument array (`$@`).

```
oprun "$1" "${@:3}"
```

Comment: hm this works nicely, but  "test string"  the quotes are missing in the result

Comment: i mean if i pass a parameter enclosed in quotes.

Comment: That's because your shell strips them.

Comment: the is no solution ?

Comment: you mean that they are not visible?

Comment: If you want the shell to ignore something then you must quote it.

Comment: It's OK that the actual quotes aren't there, the parameters will be passed correctly.